# sum elements in scala List[List[Int]]

Tags: scala

how to sum of elements in Scala `List[List[Int]]`

example :

```
val mylist = List(List(1,2,3),List(2,3,4))
```

output :

```
List(List(6),List(9))
```

Comment: `mylist.map(_.sum)`

Comment: but how can we do without using inbuilt functions

Comment: So you don't want to use `map()`, `fold()`, `apply()`, `head`, `tail`, etc? I'm sorry. I didn't realize that was part of the question.

Comment: yes without using inbuilt functions, by using pattern matching or loop statements

Comment: 1. Why wan't that included in the question? 2. What have you tried? Show us code that didn't work so we can see where you need help. 3. Pattern matching uses the inbuilt function `unapply()`.

Comment: @sureshc Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you want to do it with inbuild functions? Also, it doesn't make sense to have a list with a single integer element as a result of sum operation.

Comment: Given your requirements, it sounds like homework. You should _(at least)_ try to solve the problem by yourself. Also, what do you mean with loops? While loops? That would be a very weird solution for idiomatic **Scala**. For loops? Those does not exists in Scala, we have `for-comprenhension` which is just sugar syntax for in-built functions. Maybe you meant recursion.

Comment: What is your motivation for excluding built in functions from possible answers? And where do we draw the line of build in functions? Do you consider List#get a `build in` function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result list to be of type `List[List[Int]]` and not `List[Int]`, you can achieve it by doing this:

```
mylist.map(l => l.foldLeft(List(0))((acc, el) => List(acc(0) + el)))
```

Since `mylist.map(_.sum)` will result in an `List[Int]` you can also do it this way:

```
mylist.map(_.sum).map(List(_))
```

And if you really want to achieve it without the scala collection library, you can do it with recursion:

```
object Appz extends App {
  val mylist: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2,2,3),List(2,3,4))

  def sumSubLists(ll: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def sumList(l: List[Int], acc: Int = 0): Int = l match {
      case List() => acc
      case h :: t => sumList(t, acc + h)
    }

    @annotation.tailrec
    def sumSubListsInner(ll: List[List[Int]], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] =
      ll match {
        case List() => acc
        case h :: t => sumSubListsInner(t, acc ++ List(sumList(h)))
    }

    sumSubListsInner(ll, List())
  }

  println(sumSubLists(mylist))
}
```

Comment: In the comments, the OP specified "no builtin functions". In your code you are using seven builtin functions, I think. (I am not 100% sure how pattern matching desugars in this particular case.) Note: I find such questions stupid, and would just ignore the "no builtin functions" part of the question, but if you *do* attempt to answer it, you should not use seven builtin functions in the answer.

Comment: I agree with you on the part that questions like these, which request exclusion of build in functions, to be not particularly meaningful. But my answer provides three alternatives and you can't accumulate the number of use built in functions for all three solutions.

Comment: The third part of my question uses only one build in function. Namely `++` which can be replaced with a custom method. This only proved that not using build in functions does not make much sense since you end up writing everything on your own.

Comment: The pattern is matched against a case class constructor, namely https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html. I would not categorize this as a build in function.

Comment: The third part of your question uses `List.apply` from the `List` companion object, `List.apply` (or rather `::.apply`), `Int.+`, `List.++` (or rather `::.++`), and `println`, that's five. Like I said, I am not 100% sure how the pattern matching desugars since Constructor Patterns and Extractor Patterns are syntactically identical, and `::` is both a case class and an extractor object, I don't know which one takes precedence. So, that one may or may not use `::.unapply`. `List` is not a case class, so this one definitely uses `List.unapply`. So, depending on whether `h :: t` ends up …

Comment: … interpreted as a Constructor Pattern or Extractor Pattern, that's six or seven inbuilt functions.